# Server blocking only one IP on LAN

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, firewall

I have a server, ubuntu 16.04 server, that I use for many purposes, sites, vms, etc. I was trying to set up a reverse proxy when the server started blocking all requests from my computer, ping, any websites, plex, ssh, etc, but only that computer. I can access everything normally from my phone and any other device. It is on my lan and I did not change anything concerning the firewall.

I tried disabling the firewall, flushing iptables using sudo iptables -F, and checking the allow hosts and deny hosts files on the server.

On my computer I tried ping (can ping other sites), using different ssh programs, accessing sites, accessing plex, nothing works.

I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out it was the network I was connected to. There are two networks, 2.4 and 5 g. For my router (regular ATT router), the LANs are divided for some reason. One lan is the 2.4 g network, the other is 5 g and ehternet. My server is connected via ethernet so this was causing problems.